# Renaming columns in a loop, R

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of data frames read from an external directory of CSV's created in a loop:

```
dataList = list()
for (i in 0:length-1) {
  dataList[[i + 1]] <-
    read.csv(list.files()[length(list.files()) - i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    select(
      'Username' = USERNAME,
      'Current.count' = LOGIN.COUNT,
    ) 
}
```

The number of files stored in the directory will vary over time thus necessitating a loop.  The current count also varies across each CSV in the directory.  Later on I use left_join to join every data frame into one by username but retaining each unique user login count.  In order to to this every data frame must have a unique column name for the login count.  I have tried

```
for (i in 2:length) {
  select(Username, paste0("Count from month",toString(i))=Current.Logins)
}
```

but I get the following error

```
Error: unexpected '='
```

I get similar results when trying to user `rename()`

Comment: Do you mean to be using `select_` rather than `select` in the for loop? Probably using `setnames` or `names<-()` is easier.

Comment: You can use `select(Username, setNames(Current.logins, paste0("Count from month",toString(i)))`

Comment: @Gregor yes ``Select_() makes more sense  using set names as prescribed by @akrun.  Thank you both it's working now.

Comment: @akrun if you write that up as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I posted my comments as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with `setNames` (as @Gregor also mentioned in the comments).  We can change the `select` statement in the `for` loop to

```
for (i in 2:length) {
   select(Username, setNames(Current.logins, paste0("Count from month",toString(i)))
}
```